# Replacing String in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this string

```
var str="abc test test abc";
```

How can i replace only second occurence of "abc" string with str.replace()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the **second** occurrence of `abc`,

```
var str = "abc test test abc test abc"; 
str.replace(/\sabc/," ABC");
```

This would return,

```
`abc test test ABC test abc`
```

---

If you want to replace the **last** occurrence of `abc`, you could use,

```
var str = "abc test test abc test abc";
str.replace(/(.*)abc(.*)/,"$1ABC$2");
```

Which would return:

```
abc test test abc test ABC
```

Comment: Thank you. But if i have three "abc" string, how can i replace second occurence of "abc" string with str.replace()?

Comment: In that case you could use, `str.replace(/\sabc/," ABC");` (`\s` matches a space before `abc`, and it will only replace one match).

Comment: What about `var str = "abctesttestabctestabc"`?

Comment: @wbinglee, what about it? That is not what was asked about in the question :)

Comment: My answer can handle that case as well. :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more generic version. This will work on the *nth* occurrence of any query string to be searched and replaced in any input string.

```
var result, query = 'hello', replacement = 'good', string = 'hello hello world';

var startIndex = 0, index = 0, occurrence = 2, matches = [];

while ((index = string.indexOf(query, startIndex)) > -1) {
    matches.push(index);
    startIndex = index + query.length;
    if (matches.length === occurrence) {
        break;
    }
}

result = string.substring(0, matches[occurrence - 1]) + replacement + string.substring(matches[occurrence - 1] + query.length);

console.log(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ze6xw8mq/

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to replace the **second** one, you can use below code:

```
var secondStart = str.indexOf("abc")+"abc".length;
str.substring(0,secondStart)+str.substring(secondStart).replace("abc","new")
```

The idea is splitting the string into two parts using `indexOf`.

One **generic way** is using the callback function in `replace` method:

```
 function replaceNthMatch(originalString, searchvalue , newvalue, matchNumber)
{
   var match = 0;
   return originalString.replace(new RegExp(searchvalue, "g"), function(found){
                      match++;
                      return (match===matchNumber)?newvalue:found;
       });
}

var str = "abc test abc test abc"
console.log(replaceNthMatch(str,"abc","new",1))
console.log(replaceNthMatch(str,"abc","new",2))
console.log(replaceNthMatch(str,"abc","new",3))
```

See : http://jsfiddle.net/wbinglee/h09zt69x/